# Extract a text string with regex

Tags: regex, openrefine

I have a large set of data I need to clean with open refine.
I am quite bad with regex and I can't think of a way to get what I want,
which is extracting a text string between quotes that includes lots of special characters like " ' / \ # @ -
In each cell, it has the same format

> caption': u'text I want to extract', u'likes':

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Just wanted to have the output:
`text I want to extract`
Ibrahim solved it, thanks for taking the time to answer me!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract text string that includes lots of special characters in between, and is located between quotes `' '`, You can do it in general this way:

```
\'[\S\s]*?\'
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FyHYsE/2)

.

In your case, if you want to extract only the medial quote from this: `caption': u'text I want to extract', u'likes':` , Try this Regex:

```
(?<=u\')[\V]*?(?=\'\,)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FyHYsE/3)

Answer (score 0):

We designed OpenRefine with a few smart functions to handle common cases such as yours **without using Regex.**
Two other cool ways to handle this in OpenRefine.

1. Using drop down menu:

   - Edit Column
   - Split into several columns

     - by separator Separator '
2. Using smartSplit
   (string s, optional string sep)

   returns: array

   Returns the array of strings obtained by splitting s with separator sep. Handles quotes properly. Guesses tab or comma separator if "sep" is not given.

   `value.smartSplit("'")[2]`